# Реализовать печатную машинку

Tags: javascript

вас есть текст "Hello World".
Ваша функция имеет печатать этот текст по 1 симоволом в браузере.
КАЖДАЯ новая буква должна быть из рандомной задержкой от 0.1 до 1 секунды.
Этим самым вы симулировать написания данного текста пользователем.
Пример: "Hello"
задержки:

```
H (задержка 0.6)
e (задержка 0.1)
l (задержка 0.3)
l (задержка 0.7)
в (задержка 1) <br>
```

Как реализовать синхронизацию для асинхронных  символов

```js
function Time(string) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (string) {
        resolve(string)
      } else {
        reject("error");
      }
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 100) + 100))
  })
}
string = "Hello World";
let arr = string.split("");
for (const string of arr) {
  Time(string).then((value) => {
    console.log(value);

  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Comment: Чу-то код в вопросе переусложнен (если только целью не является изучение промисов). Такую печать можно сделать через цикл с setTimeout (который находится внутри функции и вызывает эту же функцию, пока не закончится строка).

Comment: "КАЖДАЯ новая буква должна быть из рандомной задержкой от 0.1 до 1 секунды. Этим самым вы симулировать написания данного текста пользователем." Это же много слишком, не? Даже если взять на каждый символ по 75мс (0.075с) это довольно долго получается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего использовать [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

```js
function Time(string){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (string) {
                resolve(string)
            } else {
                reject("error");
            }
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 100) + 100))
    })
}

const string="Hello World";
const arr = string.split("");

(async function main() {
  try {
    for (const string of arr) {
       console.log(await Time(string));
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: спасибо, только теперь вспомнил что async/await делает из асинхронного в синхронный

Comment: @GoodYork Кстати, вам не обязательно превращать строку в массив символов, чтобы использовать в for..of — строка сама по себе итератор, можно напрямую использовать `for (const char of string) {`.

Answer (score 1):

Немного другой способ - создаем функцию `delay` и ожидаем ее выполнения каждый  шаг цикла.

```js
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, ms)
  })
}

const string = "Hello World";

void async function main() {
  for (const ch of string) {
    const ms = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 100) + 100);
    await delay(ms);
    console.log(ch);
  }
}();
```